# Rails 7 rescue API error and stil show the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 7 app I'm using several 3rd parties API to provide fetch data. Each time I'm receiving an error I've to `rescue` with `nil` to still be able to display redirect user to desired page, e.g.:

```
# lib/custom_api.rb

module CustomApi
  extend self

  def fetch_transactions(user_id)
    client.transactions.list(user_id:)

  # rescue from custom error
  rescue Errors::NotFoundError
    nil
  end
end

# transactions_controller.rb

class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    transaction_list = CustomApi.fetch_transactions(current_user.id)

    if transaction_list
      @transactions = transaction_list
    else
      @transactions = transaction_list
      flash[:alert] = 'No transactions'
    end
  end
end

# views/transactions/index.html.erb

<%= turbo_frame_tag 'transactions' do %>
  <%= render partial: 'table_headers' %>
  <%= render Transactions::TableComponent.new(records: @transactions) if @transactions %>
<% end %>
```

Everything works well but I've got 50 endpoints where I need to include `rescue Errors::NotFoundError` and I don't think it's super sufficient to to repeat this line 50 times. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: You wrote: _it's super sufficient to repeat this line 50 times_. What line exactly do you mean? What exactly are you optimizing for?

Comment: @spickermann I meant `rescue Errors::NotFoundError nil`

Comment: In a comment to my answer, you wrote that you sometimes handle `Errors::NotFoundError` other than returning `nil`. Is there a pattern when you rescue with `nil` and when you do something different?

Comment: @spickermann I've got 114 endpoints for that API. There were at least 4 possible scenario to handle `NotFoundError` - 1. return `nil` and display a flash message inside the controller (my case); 2. displaying a flash message and `redirect_to request.referrer`; 3. `redirect_to home`; 4. call an external worker. Of course, case depends on the endpoint being called.

Answer (score 2):

In general, using [`Rescuable`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html) is the Rails' way for rescuing from exception in a centralized manner.

Add this to your `ApplicationController`:

```
rescue_from Errors::NotFoundError, with: :handle_not_found_error_from_external_api

private

def handle_not_found_error_from_external_api
  # handle the error in a generalized way, for example, by returning a response
  # that renders a modal or a toast. 
end
```

And remove these lines from your `CustomApi`:

```
# rescue from custom error
rescue Errors::NotFoundError
  nil
```

Comment: I'm aware of rescuing in a centralised way in ApplicationController but these are two issues with that: 1. is will catch all `Errors::NotFoundError` even the ones it wants to handle other than returning `nil`; 2. if I want to display an empty table in the index view (to do so I'll need transaction_list = nil) it will not be possible because this way I'll get the blank transaction_list page instead.